# TypeError: set_user_agent() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was following the tutorial of spoofing header but after making set user agent function the terminal is showing an error

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BestMoviesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'best_movies'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating,desc',
                         headers={
                             'User_Agent': self.user_agent
                         })

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a")), callback='parse_item',
            follow=True, process_request='set_user_agent'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="(//a[@class='lister-page-next next-page'])[2]"),
         process_request='set_user_agent')

 )

    def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request
```

**error**

> TypeError: set_user_agent() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use set_user_agent as a process_request method in your rules. Documentation says like this:

> process_request is a callable (or a string, in which case a method from the spider object with that name will be used) which will be called for every Request extracted by this rule. ***This callable should take said request as first argument and the Response from which the request originated as second argument.*** It must return a Request object or None (to filter out the request). (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)

So you need add response as second argument in your `set_user_agent` method.

```py
def set_user_agent(self, request, response):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request
```